# Eloquent's fillable not working with mutators

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have a following model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PaymentOption extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'payment_option';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['payment_option_code', 'payment_option_name'];

    public function setCodeAttribute($value) 
    {
        $this->attributes['payment_option_code'] = $value;
    }

    public function getCodeAttribute()
    {
        return $this->payment_option_code;
    }

    public function setNameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['payment_option_name'] = $value;
    }

    public function getNameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->payment_option_name;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have weird column names. I need mutators cause I will be accepting variables without the prefix **payment_option**.

Now, I do it in my controller like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\PaymentOption;
use App\Http\Requests\PaymentOptionRequest;

class PaymentOptionController extends Controller
{
    private $paymentOption;

    public function __construct(PaymentOption $paymentOption)
    {
        $this->paymentOption = $paymentOption;
    }


    public function create(PaymentOptionRequest $request)
    {
        $paymentOption = $this->paymentOption->fill($request->validated());

        dump($paymentOption);

        return response()->json([]);
    }
}
```

When I tried to use the fill() it doesn't call the mutators. But when I tried to set it 1 by 1 it worked like so:

```
$paymentOption->code = $validated['code'];
```

Why is that so?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that `fill` not working with mutators at all, because `fill` is from `EloquentQueryBuilder` and you are define mutators on a `PaymentOption`.

Comment: try to use `create` instead of `fill`

Comment: This did work in Laravel 5.8. Same for instantiation `new Model(['foo'=>'bar])` it stopped working for me after upgrading to Laravel 6.x. I tend not to use `fillable`, but use `protected` on a few columns instead.

Answer (score 1):

fill does loop on the input data that are in your $fillable array

```
 public function fill(array $attributes)
{
    $totallyGuarded = $this->totallyGuarded();

    foreach ($this->fillableFromArray($attributes) as $key => $value) {
        $key = $this->removeTableFromKey($key);

        // The developers may choose to place some attributes in the "fillable" array
        // which means only those attributes may be set through mass assignment to
        // the model, and all others will just get ignored for security reasons.
        if ($this->isFillable($key)) {
            $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
        } elseif ($totallyGuarded) {
            throw new MassAssignmentException(sprintf(
                'Add [%s] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [%s].',
                $key, get_class($this)
            ));
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

hence, you need to add 'code' and 'name' to the fillable array to have them assigned by fill

Answer (score 0):

With latest realese of laravel 8 there is a change in implementation of `fill`. In laravel older version `fill` method does work for mutator and database column both. But in laravel 8 implementation of `fill` method is changed now `fill` also check if the `key` given in an array to `fill` method is a database column or not.
For example if you have database column name `user_id` and `mutator` name is `user` it will not work with laravel 8. It does work for the older version of laravel.

If the `$guarded` array contains at least one column/key, then that Eloquent Model goes into a strict mode where it can only be filled with values for valid database columns. here is the test is written in the official codebase for that([link to test](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2446a91a4529ef4c4174bfd6c4a1a0bf4727820b/tests/Database/DatabaseEloquentModelTest.php#L1104-L1121)).

To solve the problem use `forceFill`. That will solve your problem.